# How can I find out the EXACT storage space of my USB drive?

Tags: usb, nautilus, storage, usb-drive

I'm planning to burn a Windows 8 image on my USB. Win is 3,9 GB, and so is my USB, according to **Files > USB > Properties**, but how can I tell the exact storage size of my USB, in case Windows is few MB more than my USB's space?

Comment: You can use mkusb or dus to create a USB install drive with Windows 7-10 from linux. See this link for mkusb-nox, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/v7#Making_a_USB_drive_to_install_Windows, this link for dus (with an improved user interface (but the same engine under the hood) https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/gui#dus_-_a_revamped_interface_of_mkusb_and_mkusb-nox, and to install either of them, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/gui#Installation

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `df -B1` in terminal to show disk size in bytes. It will output list of all disk partitions including your usb.To narrow it down, use `df -B1 /dev/sdXY` where X and Y are characteristic number and letter of your USB's device

Here's an example with 500 MB USB drive I have (and yes, it is old):

```
$ df -B 1 /dev/sdc1                                                            
Filesystem     1B-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdc1      501760000 4358144 497401856   1% /media/xieerqi/HEXMEX

$ df -H /dev/sdc1                                                              
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdc1       502M  4.4M  498M   1% /media/xieerqi/HEXMEX
```

Where you see the 1B-blocks part that's the total size, and Available part well . . .obviously the available space on disk

---

And if you're not a fan of command-line utilities, you can always use the `Disks` utility. Simply open the Unity Dash, search for `Disks`, and open the application. Below is example with that same 500 MB USB, where exact size in Bytes is given in parenthesis at the top

[image]

Comment: The "exact size in Bytes" is for the whole disk, not for the usable volume.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: `df` only inspects (mounted) file systems, so it works on volumes indeed and not on “whole disk[s]” or any other type of block device as you claim.

Comment: USB drives , unless tampered with, usually have just one partition, which is what I think you are referring to when saying "volume". So in this case, it does show size for whole disk. df command shows usage per partition, but you can always write a script or even just add pipe to awk command to sum up everything in case of hard drive. Question asks for USB, so not necessary to do that for USB

Comment: @DavidFoerster: I'm referring to the screenshot of the `Disks` utility, where Volumes are clearly enumerated individually after the total "exact size in Bytes" has been reported for the whole disk.

Comment: @Serg: "Usually" is the key word there ;)

Comment: Sure, for hard drives Disks Utility probably will report size of individual partitions in that fields. I dont have access to my laptop to verify it right now nor do i use Disks utility much to verify it from memory. Still, my case remains - for USB drives that is sufficient. We dont have to cover all the rare cases. 99% of consumer USB drives have single partition